# Cannot upgrade Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 (W: Failed to fetch http://.../ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/...)

Tags: upgrade

I cannot upgrade my ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10

This is error while i try to upgrade:

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1386276565
W: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What have i tried already?

1. Unchecked something like ..from CD-ROM.. on Ubuntu Software Center > Software Source.
2. Tried to use this command "sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*"
3. Tried to change download server

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you added an apt source for that `natty-backports` repository you see mentioned in your error. This repository is no longer available for some reason.

Find this; it will be either a line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Then delete the line or the file, save, and try again.

Comment: "Some reason" being that natty reached end of life over two years ago.